# Pause cycle all slideshow when fancybox opens

Tags: jquery, fancybox, cycle, jquery-cycle

Trying to pause slideshow when fancybox is active, can't get it to work—any suggestions appreciated.

```
 $('.section-testimonials').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    speed: 1000,
    containerResize: 0,
    timeout: 9000,
    pager:      '#slide-nav', 
    pagerEvent: 'mouseover',
    pauseOnPagerHover: true ,
    pause: 1
});

$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    'overlayColor':'#E8EEF4',
    'overlayOpacity': .9,
    'onStart': function(){
        $('.section-testimonials').cycle('pause');
    },
    'onClosed': function(){
        $('.section-testimonials').cycle('resume');
    }
});
```

Comment: it should! right!? but it isn't
check link: http://tinyurl.com/c48o78a
click on logos slideshow near bottom of page, you will still see the slideshow happening behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, you're missing a `;` after your onClosed function code:

```
$('.section-testimonials').cycle('resume')
```

Also, try using `window.parent.document`:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    'overlayColor':'#E8EEF4',
    'overlayOpacity': .9,
    'onStart': function(){
        $('.section-testimonials', window.parent.document).cycle('pause');
    },
    'onClosed': function(){
        $('.section-testimonials', window.parent.document).cycle('resume');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sam Pellino for finding the error, but still no cigar when corrected. 
tinyurl.com/c48o78a click on logos slideshow near bottom of page, you will still see the slideshow happening behind

Comment: works fine, needed to be using FULL version of cycle all, not LITE

Comment: I see! Glad you found your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution if you're using Wordpress with a fancybox and meteor slides plugin but you don't want to edit the plugin

```
//pause by default
jQuery('.meteor-slides').cycle('pause'); 

//when fancybox is closed, resume the slideshow
jQuery('#fancybox-close, #fancybox-overlay').click(function() { 
    jQuery('.meteor-slides').cycle('resume'); 
})
```